# Heap corruption after new char[strlen

Tags: c++

Currently am working on some code which is working on Win XP and on Win 7 in debug Env. But it is failing some where in  relese version with heap corruption. You help is much appreciated.

```
char *strr = NULL;
if (SomeValue!= NULL)
{
      while(SomePos != NULL)
    {
        CString strTemp; double SomeAmount; 

        strTemp.Format("%f",SomeAmount );

        strr = new char[strlen((LPCTSTR)strTemp + 1)];
        strcpy(strr,LPCTSTR(strTemp));

        if(strr)
        {
            strr = NULL;
            delete[] strr;
        }

     }
}
```

Looking this I can figure out am missing some thing in deleting the char pointer.

Comment: You should be deleting before nulling strr.

Comment: Apart from the addition bug, setting `strr` to `NULL` before deleting it will give you a memory leak. And it's OK to delete a null pointer, so you don't need the test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place. You meant to write:

```
strlen((LPCTSTR)strTemp) + 1
```

You'll therefore be allocating a buffer that is two characters shorter that it needs to be.

It would make more sense to use the `GetLength()` method:

```
strr = new char[strTemp.GetLength() + 1)];
```

And this code is clearly wrong:

```
strr = NULL;
delete[] strr;
```

Surely you cannot expect to use `delete[]` on `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. strlen((LPCTSTR)strTemp) + 1 has helped

Comment: If I was you I'd avoid strlen. It's the wrong thing to use here. And why new rather that std::vector?

Comment: I am using this strr in another function which is returning a character pointer to format the string .

Answer (score 7):

I think you meant:

```
strr = new char[strlen((LPCTSTR)strTemp) + 1];
```

this +1 is for '\0' right?